# Computing $\int _0^{\infty }e^{-b x} x^{b-1} \log \left((1-a x)^2\right)dx$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm curious if there Mathematica can be prompted to get a compact expression for the following integral for integer $b\ge 1$ and $a>0$

$$\int _0^{\infty }e^{-b x} x^{b-1} \log \left((1-a x)^2\right)dx$$

I can compute this for specific values of $b$ but the expressions quickly become large.

```
$Assumptions = {x > 0, a > 0, b >= 1};
For[b = 1, b < 6, b += 1, 
 Print@FullSimplify@
   Integrate[
    E^(-b x) x^(-1 + b) Log[(1 - a x)^2], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]]
```

However, the resulting formulas involve polynomials in $a$, so there's hope for compact expression. For instance, for $b=5$ I get

$$\frac{2 \left(5 a (a (2 a (5 a+9)+25)+25)-(4 a (3 a (2 a (a+5)+25)+125)+625) e^{-5/a} \text{Ei}\left(\frac{5}{a}\right)\right)}{3125 a^4}$$

Original [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4843188/computing-int-0-infty-e-b-x-xb-1-log-left1-a-x2-rightdx-or) from math.SE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the results can be obtained by the differentiation of a basis case (i.e. generating function)

```
$Assumptions = {x > 0, a > 0, d >= 1};
base = Integrate[E^(-d x)  Log[(1 - a x)^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]
(* -2/d * Exp[-d/a] ExpIntegralEi[d/a] *)

int[b_] := ((-1)^(b - 1) D[base, {d, b - 1}] /. d -> b) // Simplify
```

Now generate the results

```
Table[{b, int[b]}, {b, 1, 5}] // TableForm
```

We can write it in compact form as

$$I(b)= (-1)^{b}\frac{d^b}{dt^b}\left[\frac{2}{t}\frac{\text{Ei}\big(\frac{t}{a}\big)}{\exp\big(\frac{t}{a}\big)} \right]_{t=b}.$$